# Angular material MatDialog.open(Component) automatically selects first link of Component

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material matdialog.open(OrderComponent) automatically selects first link of OrderComponent(which is defined in app-routing.module.ts),but i want to navigate to “/order/edit/:id” which is a second child link of OrderComponent.
app.routing.module.ts:

```
 {
        path: 'order', children: [
          { path: '', component: OrderComponent },
          { path: 'edit/:id', component: OrderComponent }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: How does `matDialog.open()` trigger route change? Can you please clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant change the router using `matdialog`, but in your case, you can send the data into the `matdialog` based on the data change you can do whatever you want to do inside the `ordercomponent`

`matdialog.open(OrderComponent, { data: {editId: "youruniqueid" } });`